# Retrieve NVARCHAR column as datetime at SQLDeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table with a column called TIMEVALUE, it is a nvarchar2 type column. The format of the is like the  example: '29-OCT-23 05.30.03.942000000 PM' , I need to retrieve the data as '29-10-23 05.30.03' and be able to work with it as date. to_timestamp or to_datetime were working for this case.

Any suggestions?

I expect to retrieve the data from the column as datetime

Comment: Poor choice of data type. Use a proper date/time type instead, and this will become easier.

Comment: I cannot change the columns type. So i need a way to manipulate it during the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a table with a column called `TIMEVALUE`, it is a `nvarchar2` type column. The format of the is like the example: `29-OCT-23 05.30.03.942000000 PM`, I need to retrieve the data [...] and be able to work with it as date.

Use `TO_TIMESTAMP` and then `CAST` to a `DATE`:

```sql
SELECT CAST(
         TO_TIMESTAMP(
           timevalue,
           'DD-MON-RR HH12.MI.SS.FF AM',
           'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
         )
         AS DATE
       )
FROM   table_name;
```

> I need to retrieve the data as '29-10-23 05.30.03'

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type consisting of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. If **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

Therefore, if you want a `DATE` then you want a binary value with no format (and you can change the preferences on the client application to determine how the client application formats a date - in SQL Developer, you would use `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-RR HH24.MI.SS';` or use the preferences menu)

If you want a specific format, irrespective of how the client might format a date, then you want a formatted string (and not a date):

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP(
           timevalue,
           'DD-MON-RR HH12.MI.SS.FF AM',
           'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
         ),
         'DD-MM-RR HH24.MI.SS'
       )
FROM   table_name;
```

*Note: if you want the hours in a 24-hour clock then it would be `29-10-23 17.30.03`.*